# How to manage PR validation builds for 100+ projects

Tags: azure-devops

We have 100+ services/apps in a repository in Azure Devops.  We have defined a single CI/CD YAML multistage pipeline for each (build and deployment).  This limits blast radius and allows for auditability of each release of each project.  We rely on templates for all the real pipeline work so this is easy to maintain; just a small root azure-pipelines.yml file for each project that includes the needed templates.

Now, we'd like to start using PR validation builds.  And, as best as I can tell, we have two options:

1. Create a separate PR build for for every project and use the UI/API for policies to create 100+ policies
2. Create a single PR build that has stages for all 100+ projects.

I'm not a fan of the 1st option as now we'll have 200+ builds.  The 2nd option is possible, but to avoid a 3 hour PR build, we'd need a way to only run needed stages (aka project builds).

Is there a 3rd option I'm missing?  If the 2nd option is our best bet, how do we turn off stages for projects not changed in that PR (i.e. what condition would we use)?

*(FYI, our policy is to change only one project per PR, but there are, on occasion exceptions to that.)*

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the condition with commit message could help you achieve what you want? Don't hesitate to leave comment if you still has any puzzle:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For personal suggestion, I also recommend the second method. Though the build script would be very large in one configure file, but much better than have hundreds build configuration files.

But the difficulty is these 100+ apps are all in one repository. This means all the normal method will not suitable for you, include using `Build.Repository.Name` value as the stage condition. Also, there's no more details *which describing the source file path* stored in the commit.

So, I suggest you and your team developers input the `project name` info into your commit message. Then, in the build pipeline you could use the variable `Build.SourceVersionMessage` to get its comment message. Since this is a environment variable which **only** work in **step level**(Not work for **stage level** and the **job level**), it needs you add one task in the first step and use the condition for it.

The logic of it is add one step as the first one in every stages. This step is only used to conditional judgment. If the `Build.SourceVersionMessage` matches the prefix or any key contents words, the jobs will be early-exit.

If use the condition like this:

```
condition: startsWith(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], '[maven-plugin]')
```

It needs your commit message must follow a strict content writing format, starting with the specified project name.

Another condition can for you consider is:

```
condition: in(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'maven-plugin')
```

This does not need the strict content writing format, but also need input the project name in the commit message. Thus it could be evaluated in the job condition with the above script.

Hope it could give you some help.

Comment: This is a totally valid solution but we decided to use method #1 as we already had a CI build defined for every product and having a small PR build definition wasn't too much more to manage.  We've written tooling to automatically add a CI & PR definition and register PR policy for new projects.